# PostGIS "could not open extension control file" when creating extension

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I've followed the instructions here to install PostGIS 
http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt but when I went to create the extension I got the following error. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.2 and Ubuntu 12.04. The extension doesn't appear in the dropdown list on pgadmin3 either.

```
# create extension postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Comment: Here is a similar post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71302/error-when-trying-to-run-create-extension-postgis but I can't find the postgis.sql file they mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have more than one PostgreSQL install. You're connected to a PostgreSQL install from EnterpriseDB, in `/opt`. This install cannot see, or use, extensions installed into the Ubuntu-packaged PostgreSQL install.

The instructions you followed will have installed PostgreSQL 9.3 from http://apt.postgresql.org/, i.e. PGDG. You should connect to that PostgreSQL install, not the EnterpriseDB one, if you want to use the PostGIS you installed.

You need to either use the system-packaged (PGDG) PostgreSQL install on your system, or install PostGIS separately into the EnterpriseDB-packaged PostgreSQL install using their StackBuilder product.

Comment: Thanks. I tried installing PostGIS via stack builder but it didn't work, so I uninstalled everything postgresql and did `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1 postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.1` and it worked ok.

Comment: @Patrick64 You should still be able to use the 9.3 PGDG packages.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go upgrading to the new version. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this answer "Accepted"? Did it solve the problem?